# Getting error at the statement sqlCon.open "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

```
public partial class Webpages_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblnorecordfound.Visible = false;
        gvRCATracker.Visible = false;

        if (!IsPostBack) {
            //Binding control
            sqlCon.Open();
            BindPriority();
            BindProductCategory();
            BindPortfolio();
            BindRCAResponseTeam();
            BindTSMReview();
            BindRCAStatus();

            sqlCon.Close();

            SetReadOnlyForDateControls();
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to **catch** the exception and look at all the information it provides (also look at possible `.InnerException` !!)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that if your Sql server is running as the default instance,then you need to use "." in the DataSource, eg.

```
connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=LMS;User ID=sa;Password=password"
```

Otherwise, you need to specify the name of the instance of the server.

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\INSTANCENAME;Initial Catalog=LMS;User ID=sa;Password=password"
```